# String matching keywords and key phrases in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, nlp, tokenize

I am trying to perform a smart dynamic lookup with strings in Python for a NLP-like task. I have a large amount of similar-structure sentences that I would like to parse through each, and tokenize parts of the sentence. For example, I first parse a string such as `"bob goes to the grocery store"`.

I am taking this string in, splitting it into words and my goal is to look up matching words in a keyword list. Let's say I have a list of single keywords such as `"store"` and a list of keyword phrases such as `"grocery store"`.

```
sample = 'bob goes to the grocery store'
keywords = ['store', 'restaurant', 'shop', 'office']
keyphrases = ['grocery store', 'computer store', 'coffee shop']

for word in sample.split():
    # do dynamic length lookups
```

Now the issue is this Sometimes my sentences might be simply `"bob goes to the store"` instead of `"bob goes to the grocery store"`.

I want to find the keyword `"store"` for sure but if there are descriptive words such as `"grocery"` or `"computer"` before the word store I would like to capture that as well. That is why I have the keyphrases list as well. I am trying to figure out a way to basically capture a keyword at the very least then if there are words related to it that might be a possible `"phrase"` I want to capture those too.

Maybe an alternative is to have some sort of adjective list instead of a phrase list of multiple words?

How could I go about doing these sort of variable length lookups where I look at more than just a single word if one is captured, or is there an entirely different method I should be considering?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a nested for loop and a formatted string:

```
sample = 'bob goes to the grocery store'
keywords = ['store', 'restaurant', 'shop', 'office']
keyphrases = ['grocery', 'computer', 'coffee']

for kw in keywords:
    for kp in keyphrases:
        if f"{kp} {kw}" in sample:
            # Do something
```